# How to run backgroundservices on seperate thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, backgroundworker

I realized that background services blocks main thread and suddenly it makes latency in my main thread.I can't find useful resources about how to make backgroundservices to not make latency and block main thread.Any suggestions?

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, 0, 10000);
    Initialize().GetAwaiter();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async void DoWork(object state)
{
    try
    {
        //some logic
        await testService.DoWorkAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "TestBackgroundService DoWork throws ");
    }
}


private async Task Initialize()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsEnabled)
            {
                //some logic
                await testService.PrintAsync();
                IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //some logic
                await testService.CloseAsync();
                if (condition)
                {
                    IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"ExecuteAsync throws {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how do you handle currently your background service.

Comment: Simple timed backgrounservice template from microsoft docs.

Comment: I am starting timer which works every 10 seconds and does async job and another async method inside while(true)

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: I added sample code to question.

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? it has exactly what you want. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: It also says not to use `GetAwaiter`, especially not like this where it simply returns an awaiter instance that's never `await`ed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Also you're not starting the timer at all, and `StartAsync` is not an `async` function. You should probably go back to the docs

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling `Initialize().GetAwaiter();` in your code?

Comment: The issue is with `Initialize` and `while (true)` - could you explain what do you want to achieve using this construction? It should be rewritten.

Comment: I am caling Initialize.GetAwaiter cause I can't await it

Comment: How I can make Initialize to work every 5 seconds,I've tried another timer but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you confirm that "backgrounservice" is a typo before I fix it?  I assume this supposed to say "background service"?  But the same (mis-)spelling occurs multiple times, so I'm wondering if it's a class name (because, surprisingly, it turns up in searches too, so I'm being cautious before just editing it.)

Comment: Yes it is a typo

Comment: I didn't realize misspelling

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it the right way and I think scoped background task is what you want:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task

Here you have a ExecuteAsync Method and you could use it like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //your code

        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
        Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, you can create an Controller for the background jobs.

From your code, you can simply invoke the controller action using an HttpClient method.

```
private async Task ExecuteJobAsync(string jobName)
{
    // background job
    string uri = $"http://localhost:21454/api/jobs/{jobName}";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking background job:

```
private async Task Initialize()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsEnabled)
            {
                await ExecuteJobAsync("print");
                IsEnabled=false;
            }
            else
            {
                //some logic
                await ExecuteJobAsync("close");
                
                if(condition){
                    IsEnabled=true;
                }
            }
            
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"ExecuteAsync throws {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Jobs controller:

```
[Route("api/jobs")]
public class JobsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("print")]
    public void PrintAction()
    {
        // code
    }

    [HttpPost("close")]
    public void CloseAction()
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need to seperate bacgkgroundservice usage,all I need is to seperate threads which backgroundserives works and decrease latency